# Como fazer download de arquivos no Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-2

Eu tenho o caminho de uma imagem salvo no meu banco. Gostaria de colocar um botão na minha view para fazer o download dessa imagem. Como fazer?

Comment: Não sei bem como faria com cakephp mas no caso poderia usar um header: http://pastebin.com/r805nDX0 usei isto para forçar o download de um arquivo XML que está no meu banco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método [`file()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files) do objeto **response** para isso. Assim:

```
$this->response->file(
    $file['path'],
    array('download' => true, 'name' => 'foo')
);
```

Comment: Eu vou colocar isso na view?

Comment: Você coloca no *controller*, já que o objeto *response* é herdado da classe `Controller` do próprio *Cake*.

Comment: E na view como eu coloco?

Comment: Depende do método que você vai implantar. De forma simples, você precisa criar um link na sua *View* apontando para uma função no seu *controller*. Neste *controller* você implementa esse código para download do arquivo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo aqui. Criei uma action com o seu código e na view eu apntei pra essa actions.